# how can i use php codes in javascript file while php is including the javascript variable?

Tags: php, javascript

cuIzgaraKay is a javascript code I want to use it in sql command as  cuIzgaraKay.id(it gets the value correctly I checked it). However, I could not it. I googled it but I can't find what I search . How can i do it ? sorry for asking syntax error but I can't find it maybe ı have logical error

```
        if(cuIzgaraKay){



          <?php
              include_once('../phps/kutuphane/inc.php');


    $result = mysql_query("select id from bolge_db where parent_id="?>+ cuIzgaraKay.id + <?);
```

Comment: JavaScript can't interact with PHP like this. PHP is serverside, while JS is clientside, so the only interactions would really be via AJAX.

Comment: when $result line is put on the codes win does not open and couldn't find the the win error when i write number instead of cuızgarakay.id it works correctly

Comment: @Blender I agree, HTTP POST/GET using AJAX would be the "standard way" of doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you're trying to execute an SQL query from the PHP page, using data from the Javascript code you're generating.

**The Javascript is only evaluated on the client side of your page. That means that the server-side cannot know anything about the Javascript code.**

What you need to do, is to generate the ID, and communicate it to the PHP backend, for example with a HTTP POST/GET request or something.

**EDIT:**

If you're new to Javascript, I'd suggest you look into the native JS object XMLHttpRequest. You use it like this:

```
/*
    params:
            url:     relative URL on host, e.g. '/users/morten/data'
            method:  GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD or OPTIONS
            data:    data to send with request, e.g. POST form-data
            ok_cb:   function to call on success
            fail_db: function to call on failure
*/
function http_req(url, method, data, ok_cb, fail_cb) {
    var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    client.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(client.readyState == this.DONE) {
            if(client.status == 200 || client.status == 302 || client.status == 304)
                ok_cb(...);
            else
                fail_cb(...);
        }
    };
    client.open(method, url, true);
    client.send(data);
}
```

Or you can use jQuery or a ton of other frameworks to do the same thing.

**EDIT:**

> what is method in there how can i write there and how can i get data from php – user1702486

The method is whatever HTTP request method you want to use. See the wikipedia page for more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods

This code will POST to `/page.php` sending a data-string along.
If the request returns a successful code, the `ok`-callback will be called.

```
// handle HTTP OK
var ok = function(meth, res, url) {
    console.log("OK: got " + res);
}

// handle all else
var fail = function(meth, res, url) {
    console.log("UTTER UTTER FAILURE!\n" + res);
}

// make a HTTP POST to server/page.php sending the data along
// you can serialize the data and use XML or JSON or whatever instead
http_req("/page.php", "POST", "username=usr&password=passw&userid=12345", ok, fail);
```

On the PHP page, you will need to handle the POST by checking the data and returning an answer if appropriate. Something like this:

```
<?php
if (empty($_POST))
{
    print_r($_POST);
    ...
    // do something with the data and print something back
}
?>
```

If you've posted "data1=1234&data2=5678&str=hello%20mum" the $_POST array will look like this:

```
(
    [data1] => 1234
    [data2] => 5678
    [str] => "hello%20mum"
)
```

Comment: thanks can you give any link including examples calling php file by sending data and getting data I tried some examples but it does not work

Comment: I'll make you a quick example of JS code making a HTTP request to a PHP page. Just give me a minute :)

Comment: how can i get the return value coming from php

Comment: thanks but :) my php url returns only one value and how can i keep iT ı guess that it changes there f(client.readyState == this.DONE) {
            if(client.status == 200 || client.status == 302 || client.status == 304)
                ok("POST","res","../phps/dbController.php"); I think res value must be from php is it true?

Comment: Yes, `res` will be a string containing the result from the server. Call `ok` like this `ok(res)`.

Comment: ok reallyi thanks, but I still can't do it maybe I couldn't tell you what I want. I can't get the value coming from php-url

Answer (score 2):

You can't, javascript is client side and php is server side. So the php code gets executed before the javascript.